# Delimiting output in Lisp

Tags: formatting, lisp, common-lisp

I'm sure this is a very basic question, but how to output delimited values?

```
(defun q (n)
    (if (<= n 2)
        1
        (+
            (q (- n (q (- n 1))))
            (q (- n (q (- n 2)))))))

(loop for x from 1 to 25
     do (
        write (q x)))
```

The above outputs the first 25 terms of the Hofstadter Q-sequence, but concatenated:

```
11233455666888109101111121212121614
```

Can be comma-, space- or tab-delimited. I tried playing with the `format` function, but it's way over my head for a Lisp newbie like me.

Comment: For tests "print" is sufficient, and adds a newline. Or just `collect` elements in a list and the REPL will print it, it will be formatted decently and is also likely to be readable back as Lisp data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the delimiter yourself, e. g. `(write ", ")`.  You can also write the (platform dependent) line separator with `(terpri)`.

As for `format`, you can get by with some basic usage at first:

```
(format <stream> <template> <args…>)
```

- `<stream>` is where the output should go.  For standard output, use `t`.  In order to write to a file, you would use the stream created by `with-open-file` here.
- `<template>` is a template string.  That's just a string, but the `~` character is special.  For starters, just use `~a` wherever you want to insert an argument.
- `<args…>` are exactly as many further arguments as you used `~a` above.

Using this simple toolbox, you could do: `(format t "~a, " (q x))` for each item.

Format has a lot of other possibilities, e. g. it can iterate a list by itself, do different output formats and escaping, or even be extended by user functions.  Look that up in the hyperspec (e. g. at clhs.lisp.se).

Answer (score 2):

use [`write-char`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_cha.htm) or, indeed, [`format`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_format.htm):

```
(format t "~D: ~:D~%" x (q x))
```